# Skipping a part of a line using sed

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, scripting

I have a file with content like so - `@1: 00001109`
Each line is of the same format. I want the final output to be `@1: 00 00 11 09`.

I used command in sed to introduce a space every 2 characters - `sed 's/.\{2\}/& /g'`. But that will give me spaces in the part before the colon too which I want to avoid. Can anyone advise how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '{gsub(/../,"& ",$2);sub(/ +$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** First globally substituting each 2 digits pair with same value by appending space to it where `gsub` is globally substitution to perform it globally). Once this is done, using single `sub` to substitute last coming space with NULL to avoid spaces at last of lines.

---

---

With `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{2}/& /g;s/ +$//'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Globally substituting each pair of digits with its same value and appending spaces to it. Then substituting space coming last space of line(added by previous substitution) with NULL.

Comment: Can you explain how it skips the part before the colon though? I didn't get that completely.

Comment: @Nibhrit, sure, your string `@1: 00001109` is space delimited and in `awk` default field separator is space so your digits part came in 2nd field and I am performing substitutions in 2nd field only hence 1st field with colon one is never affected, kindly do let me know in case of more queries here, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9]\B/& /g' file
```

After a pair of digits within a word, insert a space.

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` happens to be your option, how about:

```
perl -pe '1 while s/(\d+)(\d\d)/$1 $2/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pure bash:

```
for line in "$(<your_file.txt)"; do
    first=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1`" "
    last=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2`
    for char in `seq 0 2 ${#last}`; do
        first+=${last:$char:2}" "
    done;
done;
```